# Dynamic Loading Grids; Javascript or Tag library

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dhtml, taglib, pagedlist

I am looking for a grid implementation on my dashboard. The requirement here is that if the data that the grid might be fetching changes while a user is looking through the grid, the changes should be reflected. So the row present in page 1 may be present in page 2 after sometime. If the user clicks on page 2, he should be shown a fresh page that is fetched from database and that item should be in page 2. So, I need to use a pagedObjectList to get the data and show that data when user looks for the next page. The same requirement is for sorting too.

So I am looking for a javascript Grid like jqGrid or DHTMLX grid or a Tag Library which has some sort of ajax calling mechanism for sorting and paging instead of showing the old data which is fetched first.

Please suggest any grid/ tag library implementation which can fulfill the above mentioned requirement. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I finally went with DHTMLXGrid, it has all the configurable actions I needed, like onPageAction, onSort etc. I could simple write my custom code for those trigger events. I would also recommend it to others, pretty handy and solid.